# I perform Ajax calls every second but if the content's changed then I replace the image source. which causes the image to break

Tags: javascript

I have a radio broadcast from LastFM. So in order to stay updated, I have to send ajax call's every second. If the data changes my image source should be changed as well as the title. But in my case the title changes and the image breaks.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'urltolastfm',
  success: function(data) {
    if ($('#thumbnail').attr('src') !== data.recenttracks.track[0].image[3]['#text']) {
      $('#thumbnail').hide();
      $('#thumbnail').attr('src', data.recenttracks.track[0].image[3]['#text']); // this is where i change the source
      $('#thumbnail').show();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by the image breaks? Is there any errors in the console?

Comment: Nothing here touches the title.

Comment: @sundaycode I suspect he means he gets a broken image icon. Which means that `data.recenttracks.track[0].image[3]['#text']` is not a valid URL.

Comment: What happens when you set breakpoints on that success callback to observe what `data` actually is? (Or when you add console.log statements) ?

Comment: I'll bet it's not a full URL, maybe just the filename. You need to prefix it with the hostname.

Comment: `console.log(data.recenttracks.track[0].image[3]['#text']);` - ?

Comment: I even tested the url it is also working. by broken image I mean to say that I see a small image icon but not the image. When I open the chrome due to so many ajax calls it says insufficient resource

Comment: Its the url of the image if you console.log

Comment: what is the exact value of `data.recenttracks.track[0].image[3]['#text']` - including leading/trailing spaces for example

Comment: Can you come on the remote. I can show you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual error was that I was making an ajax call on the loading of the page, then on with every second the ajax call was made and making it change the paragraph line with the data. It caused data overflow. So I created one single ajax call as a function and then use a timeout to recall it.

```
  function checkThumbnail() {
            if ($('#thumbnail').length > 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        function fetchdata() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getRecentTracks&user=evillarreal42&api_key=6c7cf66516c75e782226590e933f6c6b&format=json&limit=1',

                success: function(data) {
                    if ($('#thumbnail').attr('src') !== data.recenttracks.track[0].image[3]['#text']) {
                        $('#lastfm').empty().append(
                            '<h6 class="marg" style="margin-bottom:10px;  text-align:center;"><span class="mon" style="color:black; text-align:center">● Now playing → "' +
                            data.recenttracks.track[0].name + '" by ' + data.recenttracks.track[0]
                            .artist['#text'] + ' from ' + data.recenttracks.track[0].album[
                                '#text'] + ' </span></h6>');
                        if (!checkThumbnail()) {
                            $('#foot').fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );
                            var img = $('<img id="thumbnail">'); //Equivalent: $(document.createElement('img'))
                            img.attr('src', data.recenttracks.track[0].image[3]['#text']);
                            img.css({
                                "position": "absolute",
                                "top": "50%",
                                "left": "50%",
                                "width": "250px",
                                "height": "250px",
                                "margin-top": "-125px",
                                /* Half the height */
                                "margin-left": "-125px",
                                "display": "none",
                                "z-index": "22" /* Half the width */
                            });
                            img.appendTo('.bgg');
                        } else {
                            $('#thumbnail').attr('src', data.recenttracks.track[0].image[3]['#text']);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(fetchdata, 1000);});
```